# Token generated by Rails API do not have permission to do anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, token

I wrote a token authentication back-end with ruby on rails, but my problem is that even providing the generated token in the header, it will fail.

This is the class file that will authorize a request to the API:

```
class AuthorizeApiRequest
  prepend SimpleCommand

  def initialize(headers = {})
    @headers = headers
  end

  def call
    user
  end

  private

  attr_reader :headers

  def user
    @user ||= User.find(decoded_auth_token[:user_id]) if decoded_auth_token
    @user || errors.add(:token, 'Invalid token') && nil
  end

  def decoded_auth_token
    @decoded_auth_token ||= JsonWebToken.decode(http_auth_header)
  end

  def http_auth_header
    if @headers['Authorization'].present?
      return @headers['Authorization'].split(' ').last
    else
      errors.add(:token, 'The token is missing')
    end
    nil
  end
end
```

I can confirm the `http_auth_header` method does receive the `Authentication` header value. `puts @headers['Authorization']` show it.

Below's the class that will encode and decode the token

```
class JsonWebToken
  class << self
    def encode(payload, exp = 24.hours.from_now)
      payload[:exp] = exp.to_i
      JWT.encode(payload, Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base)
    end

    def decode(token)
      body = JWT.decode(token, Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base)
      HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(body)
    rescue
      nil
    end
  end
end
```

Not sure what else to show.

Comment: Its hard to see, but did you log "@headers['Authorization'].split(' ').last" ? Are you sure thats parsed correctly? And are you sure your *JsonWebToken* is loaded?

Comment: Yes, I logged it and it showed the token. About the other questions: no, hehe.